# Gmail only reads my emails when I press the 'refresh' button - is this normal

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, 2.1-eclair, gmail

On my Samsung Galaxy S, gmail only loads new emails when I press the 'refresh' button.

Is this normal ? Or should I set some options somewhere ?

I thought gmail should push emails to the phone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In answer to my own question (and in thanks for the answer already provided), but the problem was that in my office, my phone uses Wifi router which is connected to the internet via a **firewall** . And on this firewall **one of the necessary imap ports was blocked**.

My collegue changed this setting , and now gmail is behaving as expected.

*I am really not in the habit of choosing my own answers as the selected answer, but for this question, this was the solution.*

Hope it helps others !

Comment: Nice detective work! ;)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with selecting your own answer if it's what solved the problem _for you_.

Comment: Of course, if you had mentioned that this was only occurring at work while you were using the Corporate wifi, you might have gotten different answers.

Comment: @Al Everett: I agree, I should have edited my question. I did mention in in my reply to your answer, though. Problem is, you have a new device, you play around with it. Use it here , use it there and notice something not working. The first thought is that you are doing something wrong. Second thought is , asking it to the nice people at Android.Stackexchange. Than you use the device or program some more and slowly start to see a pattern emerging. In the end a solution is found, either by reading answers, of by yourself. So I answered my own question in the hope that it will help someone else.

Answer (score 5):

From the Home screen, go to `Settings | Accounts & sync | <your account>` and make sure that "Sync Gmail" is checked.

Comment: @ Al E.: This was already checked. And it seems to work. Seems I say because it can take a long time for a mail to arrive. Is there any way we can adjust the time period Gmail uses to push the mails in our direction ? And another thing: does the phone needs to be displaying it's screen ? I have the impression that mails never arrive when my phone is black (is running but not displaying anything).

Comment: @Edelcom: I don't know what to tell you. Gmail to my Moto Droid works great, whether the screen is on or not.

Comment: @Al E.: So it does now here at home (connected to local wifi). Strange. It did not do that yesterday when I was working at my office (also connected to local wifi). Will have to investigate that a bit further. Thanks for your answer, though.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what Al E. says, you also need to make sure Syncing is general is on.  Form the Home screen go to `Settings | Accounts and sync` and make sure both `Background data` and `Auto-sync` are checked.

Comment: +1 for providing more steps that are vital. Also, inside the account entry, you need to check "Sync Gmail" (to get the mail data-type). It also shows the last sync time-date as well.